# SFNTLY: How to convert any font that gets uploaded to "WOFF" format?

Tags: java, fonts, type-conversion

I can not find any documenration on this library (https://code.google.com/p/sfntly/). I've been taking stabs at it for 2 days now. I'm trying to convert any font that gets uploaded to "WOFF" format.

Could someone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source code of SFNTLY I am no expert in sfntly, so use my answer at your risk :).

I would convert the font with WoffWriter#convert() to writeable font data, then copy the wfd to outputstream.

```
    WoffWriter ww = new WoffWriter();
    WriteableFontData wfd = ww.convert(yourFont);
    try {
        FileOutPutStream fs = new FileOutputStream("out.fnt");
        wfd.copyTo(fs, wfd);
        fs.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully converted my TTF into a WOFF file by following these steps:

- Download and install ant following "The Short Story" steps (http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#getBinary)
- Download SFNTLY via SVN checkout (https://code.google.com/p/sfntly/source/checkout) and followed the steps contained into the file "sfntly\java\quickstart.txt"

Created a new java project and imported the following four jars I created following the previous steps into my project:

- sfntly.jar
- woffconverter.jar
- guava-16.0.1.jar

I slightly tweaked display_name code which contained a few syntax mistakes.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import com.google.typography.font.sfntly.Font;
import com.google.typography.font.sfntly.FontFactory;
import com.google.typography.font.sfntly.data.WritableFontData;
import com.google.typography.font.tools.conversion.woff.WoffWriter;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        WoffWriter ww = new WoffWriter();
        FontFactory fontFactory = FontFactory.getInstance();
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            bytes = Files.toByteArray(new File("C:\\FontName.TTF"));
            Font font = fontFactory.loadFonts(bytes)[0];
            WritableFontData wfd = ww.convert(font);

            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("out.fnt");
            wfd.copyTo(fs);
            fs.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```